# when we talk about settlement in litigation, can we use the word "price"?

Tags: vocabulary, legalese

When we talk about settlement in litigation, can we use the word "price"?
I feel "amount" is commonly use when we talk about the amount of money one side has to pay to the other.
Can we also use "price" in this context? 
For instance, can we say like "My lawyer successfully negotiated with the opponent, so I was able to reach a settlement agreement with a very low price".
I feel it is wrong, but I can't tell why.

Comment: A price is the amount of money required to purchase something; a monetary settlement is part of an agreement, so technically, you're not buying anything.

Comment: It's *unusual*, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's *wrong*. (Although it probably is wrong if used in legal writing.) It would be appropriate in the context of a clearly stressed metaphor.